# Can you roll for HP at levelup in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-advancement, dnd-adventurers-league, hit-points

Are you allowed to roll for your hit points when gaining a level in Adventurers League,or do you have to take the fixed value?  A DM I played with today told me I had to use the fixed value, but I could not find that in the Player's Guide.

Comment: Very nice self-answer.

Comment: I swear I read through the whole handbook and it wasn't there until I asked the question.  I only found it because I looked back a version 6 and version 6 had a bold section for the rule that got condensed in version 7.

Comment: I understand your frustration with the rule books, it happened to me too. But I feel like i have to explain myself: my comment above was 100% sincere.We [encourage self-answers FAQ style](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and our [goal is to make a knowledge library](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal), covering from the basics to the most esoteric topics.+1, good job.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I found it, page 5 of version 7.0 of the AL players guide.

> When you gain a level, use the fixed hit point
>   value in your class entry. You can’t roll your hit points.

Missed that but easily fixed.